# Is there a way to zoom in Zoom?

Tags: zoom, zoom-meeting

Is it possible to zoom (the action) on an incoming Zoom (the software) video stream? The double use of "zoom" makes this hard to Google. I'm interested in any platform Zoom (the software) supports.

Comment: On Mac you can just drag the window larger, or use system zoom to magnify the whole screen.

Comment: @Tetsujin Thank you! System zoom should work on any OS that offers it, right?

Comment: idk how system zoom works on any other OS, sorry.